# Eyeglass prescription

Tags: optometry, glasses

Question edited as per advice. When prescribing eyeglasses, is there an aspect of balance between magnification and astigmatism correction? should the magnification strength be reduced when increasing the astigmatism correction or are these two issue unrelated?

Comment: There's a legitimate question in here but it's so mixed up with your personal details that I can't find it. Could you please reconsider your question and edit it to comply with site requirements?